# 'appStoreReceiptURL' is unavailable: not available on iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am getting a strange compiler error:

[appStoreReceiptURL docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/appStoreReceiptURL) say we need to use NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1 to ensure whether we can run the method, but my app targets ios 5.0 sdk so this macro doesn't even exist and does not compile.

So I tried the following, but I'm getting a different compiler error:
'appStoreReceiptURL' is unavailable: not available on iOS

```
                if (([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"6.1" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)) {
                    receipt = t.transactionReceipt;
                } else {
                    // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
                    receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]];
                }
```

any ideas on how to run this method correctly & safely?

Comment: Why can't you use the latest SDK and set the Deployment target to iOS 5?

Comment: I *am* doing as you suggest: base SDK is set to "6.1" (xcode 4.6.3) and target OS is 5.0.

Comment: Then why would the solution that Apple provided not work, since the macro is compile time it will only need to be in the SDK that you are building with. If used the macro lots of times in my iOS 7 project with some specific iOS 6 options. The `NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1` does not even exists in the iOS 6.1 SDK.

Comment: The solution by apple does not work because it causes a compiler error. I will have to switch to xcode 5.0 and use a base sdk of 7.0 if I want that macro to exist... correct?

Comment: Yes the `NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1` is only available in the iOS 7 SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked finally, at least as long as I am using xcode 4.6.x, is to try/catch the appStoreReceiptURL call, and check if there is an Illegal Argument exception. If so, fallback to getting the reciept the old fashion way from the SKPaymentTransaction.transactionReceipt property.

When I switch to Xcode 5.x, I will change the code to the one Apple suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation suggests the following:

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
    {
        // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier
    } 
else
   {
        // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
        NSURL *receiptUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
        NSLog(@"receiptUrl %@",[receiptUrl path]);
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[receiptUrl path]])
        {
            NSLog(@"exists");

        } else {
            NSLog(@"does not exist");
        }

    }
```

As it specifies:

> Note: The general best practice of weak linking using the
>   respondsToSelector: method cannot be used here. Prior to iOS 7, the
>   method was implemented as private SPI, but that implementation called
>   the doesNotRecognizeSelector: method.

On this site: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html